# How I can send my app to iphone using Worklight on Linux

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I'm using workload studio 5.0.5 plugin on Eclipse (Linux) thus I can't install XCode and I don't have an application center server (except if there is one buildin worklight studio and I'm not aware of).
All docs I found to test/send my application on iphone/ipad are based on XCode.

I wonder if somebody knowns or can point me on doc explaining how I can test my app running on Linux Eclipse.

PS: I have an iphone/ipad, so what I looking for is a way to create the ipa file and send it to one of these devices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need a Mac to create the IPA file.

Comment: This is disappointing... Just for my info, if I have a Mac can I use the Android emulator and build the android app?

Comment: Yes, you can build android APK's from a Mac.

Comment: @ITDoVe: There are a lot of services that allow you to use a Apple's Operating System without buying an Apple Computer. For example: [MacinCloud](http://www.macincloud.com/), you pay per usage. I haven't tried them, so your millage may vary. There are also virtualization tools like [VMWare](https://www.vmware.com/) and [Virtual Box](https://www.virtualbox.org/) and [online tutorials](http://lifehacker.com/5583650/run-mac-os-x-in-virtualbox-on-windows) that could help you setup an iOS dev environment on your Linux machine.